# How to get Google Analytics report: visited page X then (optionally) triggered event Y

Tags: google-analytics

I need to know how many people visited my login page, and then (optionally) triggered an event on the page that I have set up. (To be clear: the event tracking is already set up and works perfectly. This question is about how to get a report from the data.)

So I need a report like:

- X people visited login page but never triggered event
- X people visited login page, triggered event 1
- X people visited login page, triggered event 2

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This here is literally minimum information you provided but i will try: You can if you set up events through GTM configure triggers to fire only on specific page, in this case login page. That way you will get how many people triggered specific events on specific page. And if you wanna see the other side, by default you can see how many users visited your page, Just create custom report, where you have all users for that page only, add custom segments for users that triggered event, and there you have it.

Comment: All the events are done and set up and working-- I don't need help with that. I need help generating a report. For example, I need to know how many people visited the login page and triggered NO events, how can I do that? Would I set that up as a segment that includes everyone who hit 'login' page but has none of the events?

Comment: Segments will be the way to go here. Does order matter? That is, do you care that the login page visit happen before the event? (Perhaps it is not possible to trigger the event without visiting the login page first - then order will just come for free)

Comment: Just create the "negative" segment, instead "include" user with event you set "exclude" that users, and you will got the report you want. Customize as much as you can.